# When should I load data from isolated storage for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

Microsoft's best practices state:

If an application relies on data from isolated storage, you should not load this data in the Launching event handler or in the Activated event handler. Disk operations can take several seconds and these events are called before the application is loaded and active, so accessing Isolated Storage in these handlers results in a long wait time as the application loads. Instead, you should load data from Isolated Storage asynchronously, after the application has loaded.

Why is this, and when should data be read from isolated storage?

What I'm looking to load is if the phone user has their username/password persisted to isolated storage, and preloading those for login on the first screen.  When should this action take place?

thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't store the password. Ever! Anywhere! Store a salted hash of the password. If you need to store this to pass to a webservice (or similar) have the webservice return a token on successful login and store that instead.

Now, your actual question.
You've answered the first part of it yourself though.

Because you want the application to be responsive, when the application launches you should perform timely operations off of the UI thread.

Data should be loaded from and saved to IsolatedStorage at times which are most appropriate to the application, the volume of data and the frequency with which it is needed or updated.

In your specific instance, I wouldn't expect the retrieval of 2 strings from isolated stroage to be very slow at all and so I would perform their retrieval in the `Loaded()` event of the page in question.

If you were just retrieving a username and password I would consider using [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28VS.95%29.aspx) to persist these.

If you also had lots of other details to store and needed these at about the same time you may want to store them all together so you could retrieve them all together.

Comment: Thanks Matt, great answer.  Yeah, I'll store a salted hashed password when/if this thing becomes non-trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The motivation to defer loading of data from isolated storage until the app is loaded, and to do it asycnrhonously is two-fold.

1. There is a lot of work being done to load the app on these resource constrained devices. If it's practical for your app to do so, then defering any actions until after the app is responsive will improve the user experience. Noting also that you have a cert reqt of 5s to show something and 20s to be responsive - and some devices are slower/faster than others.
2. Async is good for any non trivial operations so that you don't block the UI thread and interfere and cause the device to appear not fully responsive.

It's worth keeping in mind that the phone may be doing things you haven't considered in the background in additional to your normal low load testing scenarios - such as syncing mail.

I concur with Matt, that loading 2 strings, for the sake of login credentials, is *probably* not going to cause you a performance issue.

If you wanted to be ultra diligent, you could load that data asynchronously after the login page is loaded and have the controls disabled until such time as that data is retrieved.